# 3 divs: one centered div with max-width and left,right divs that should take the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs. One div is centered and 2 divs located from left and right sides. The centered div has max-width of 400 px.
Here is the CSS

```
#left{float: left;background-color: red;height:100%;}
#right{float: right;background-color: green;height:100%}
#center{max-width:400px;margin: auto;background-color: blue;height:100%}
#container{width:100%;height:50px;}
body{color:white;}
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div  id='container'>
    <div  id='left'>
    left
    </div>
    <div  id='right'>
    right
    </div>
    <div  id='center'>
    center
    </div>
</div>
```

I also prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ord9mp1a/1/).
I need left and right divs to be "stretched" to center div.

Comment: Add this code  `#right, #left {width:15%}`

Comment: Using flex: https://jsfiddle.net/ord9mp1a/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc) function.

Specifically:

```
width: calc(50% - 200px);
```

Since the width of the center element is 400px and both sides are equal, you can simply calculate the width for both sides by taking 50% of the total width minus 200px (representing half of the center element). This gets you the width between the viewport edge and the edge of the center element.

[Can I Use support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for calc().

Try it out below:

```css
#left {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 200px);
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 200px);
}
#center {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    left
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
    right
  </div>
  <div id='center'>
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have  nothing against using flex, it will make it easy.

Below without reordering your HTML structure but using `order` in CSS to set `#center` at `center` :) .

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#container > div {
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
background:yellow;
}
#container > div#center {
  max-width: 400px;
  order: 2;
  
  /* let'see it */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, gray 50%, lightgray 50%) left no-repeat;
  border: solid;
  background-size: 398px auto;/* show the last 2 pixel blank when max-width reached */
}
#container > div#right {
  order: 3
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    left
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
    right
  </div>
  <div id='center'>
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `calc()` function :

```
#left{float: left;background-color: red;height:100%; width: calc(50% - 200px);}
#right{float: right;background-color: green;height:100%; width: calc(50% - 200px);}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ord9mp1a/5/)

`200px` represents half of the center width container and `50%` because there are two containers of each side (left and right)